# cakephp pagination change urls to make them more seo friendly

Tags: php, url, cakephp, seo

I am using this syntax:

```
<ul>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev($this->Html->image('arrow_left.png', array('border' => 0, 'tag'=>'li')), array('escape'=>false, 'tag'=>'li')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'tag'=>'li')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next($this->Html->image('arrow_right.png', array('border' => 0, 'tag'=>'li')), array('escape'=>false, 'tag'=>'li')); ?>
</ul>
```

which creates me links like

```
<li>
<a href="/mycontrollername/search/cat:1/page:4?url=slugged_url">4</a>
```

Is there any way, that I can get rid of the controller and action in the url and use instead the url parameter?

I mean instead of getting links like

```
http://domain.com/mycontrollername/search/cat:1/page:2?url=slugged_url
```

I would like to get something like

```
http://domain.com/slugged_url/cat:1/page:2
```

Is that possible? 
If yes, how?

I have the same issue with results per page:

```
<?php
$sortDir = ($this->Paginator->sortDir() == 'asc') ? $this->Paginator->sortDir(): 'desc';
$text = ($sortDir == 'asc')? __('aufsteigend', true):__('absteigend', true);
echo $this->Paginator->sort('OBJ_PREIS', $text, $options = array('escape' => false, 'direction'=>'DESC', 'class' => 'asc'))`;
?>
```

Can I change the urls there as well?

Please advice!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using routes. A route will rewrite the URL to something "pretty".

Check the offical CakePHP book. [It has a complete chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) just about routing.

The book as plenty of examples for different things you can do with routes as well.

Comment: I work with routes already a lot to get my seo friendly urls working. But in this particular area, I can't find a proper solution, therefore I was asking here. I also thought that not the routing is the issue, it is based in the view and the syntax of the pagination. When I get the links there in the right way, I will be able to get the right routing. But first I have so solve the view. Is there the possibility to describe you the problem more detailled? With a live url? Can I contact you?

Comment: Did you read this? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html The page explains this very well. No need to explain it any further, the problem is clear and it's solutions is very clearly explained in the CakePHP book. And no, sorry, I'm not giving private lessons, at least not unpaid.

Comment: As I really have to solve this issue I even don't mind to pay for an expert help. Yes I know the page quite well. But for some reason, I can't find the solution there. I don't find the point, where the routing rule will "overwrite" me the urls I output in the view... My routing rules working fine for the urls when I call them in the browser in the way I would like to have them. But I can't figure out how I can use a route to "formate" my urls from http://domain.com/mycontrollername/search/cat:1/page:2?url=slugged_url into the wished format http://domain.com/slugged_url/cat:1/page:2